# zsh does not start as login shell

Tags: boot, terminal, shell, zsh

Running Debian I have set `zsh` as my login shell in `/etc/passwd` and zsh is among the permitted shells.

```shell
$ cat /etc/shells
# /etc/shells: valid login shells
/bin/sh
/bin/bash
/usr/bin/bash
/bin/rbash
/usr/bin/rbash
/bin/dash
/usr/bin/dash
/bin/zsh
/usr/bin/zsh
$ id
uid=1000(re) gid=1000(re) groups=1000(re),20(dialout),24(cdrom),25(floppy),27(sudo),29(audio),30(dip),44(video),46(plugdev),109(netdev),113(bluetooth),118(scanner)
$ grep re: /etc/passwd
re:x:1000:1000:xxxxXXXXX,,,:/home/re:/bin/zsh
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/zsh
```

Despite all these setting the system starts a bash shell whenever I open a new console.

```
$ ps -p $$
PID TTY          TIME CMD
4435 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
```

Manually starting a zsh does not show any problems. On a second computer I don't have that problem and zsh starts flawlessly in all new terminals.

Comment: What do you mean by "whenever I open a new console"? A GUI terminal emulator? What terminal emulator? Is it configured to run `bash`? E.g. my `konsole` is configured to run `bash` and it has nothing to do with `/etc/passwd`.

Comment: As an aside: Kamil is posing good questions, but don’t reply to them with a comment. Instead, use the requested to update your question. Your‘re more likely to get an answer that way.